# ASP.NET MVC list with jQuery-links

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

While I'm just starting with ASP.NET MVC and jQuery, I cannot even solve a quite simple task...

I am using a strongly-typed view to display a list of products, where every li-element gets a unique id:

```
<ul id="product-list">    
  <% foreach (var item in Model.Products)
    { %>   

        <li <%= "id=\"product_" + item.Id + "\"" %> >  
            <div class="item">
               <%= item.Name %>  
            </div>
        </li>     

  <% } %>
</ul>
```

Now I want to attach to the click-event of every single li-element, so that if the user clicks on a div-element, detailed product-informationen should be loaded asynchronously into a details-pane.

I know how I can use jQuery to invoke an action-method ajax-style and also how to display the json-result which contains the product-details, BUT I have no idea, **how I could attach the onclick-event to every single div, so that I can use the productId to load the details**.

Can someone please give me some tips, how I could solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use the [Attribute Starts With selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to select all list items with ID attribute starting with 'product', and [String.split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) to extract the product id from the ID attribute of the clicked LI, e.g.:

```
$("li[id^=product]").click(function() {
    // split the ID at the '_' to get the product ID (demo)
    alert(this.id.split('_')[1]);

    // loadDetails would contain your ajax method or whatever,
    // it takes the product ID as its argument
    loadDetails(this.id.split('_')[1]);
});
```

Example `loadDetails()` implementation using [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

```
function loadDetails(id) {
    $.get('products.aspx', {id: id}, function(html) {
        $("#productView").html(html);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all of the list elements on the page represent products:

```
$(function() {
    $('li').click( function() {
         var id = $(this).attr('id').replace(/product_/,'');
         $.ajax({
             url: '<%= Url.Action("details","product") %>/' + id,
             dataType: 'json',
             type: 'get',
             success: function(data) {
                  ...show the details...
             }
         });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This answer helps me that much, as well as all the other answers!

Answer (score 0):

you can use following jquery to bind a `click` event to all the divs inside Li. and then make your ajax call.

```
$('#product-list li>div').bind('click',function(){

    // get the current li Id
    var currentLiId = $(this).parent().attr('id');

    alert(currentLiId);

    // make your ajax call here.
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This answer helps me that much, as well as all the other answers!

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a click event handler to each div:

```
$("#product-list>li div.item").click(function() {...});
```

Within that function, 'this' will be the div. The parent li has the "id" attribute you're interested in:

```
$(this).parent().attr("id")
```

From there, you should be able to get the product id. jQuery supports an AJAX load method, which you can use on the target div:

```
$("#results").load("/Product/Details/" + myProductId);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This answer helps me that much, as well as all the other answers!